# How to fetch data from sqlite3 without using while 1 and if

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm currently using this method of fetching data from `sqlite3` database:

```
while(1){
   rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
   if(rc == SQLITE_ROW){
       ...
   }
   else if(rc == SQLITE_DONE){
       break;
   }
}
```

What I do not like about this is `if else` construct, which looks rather clunky here. And besides, everyone knows that `if else` is evil. So, probably there is another method of fetching data from `sqlite`, something like:

```
while(sqlite3_step(stmt)){
   ...
}
```

Or, probably, there is a fetch method or something similar to that.

I just want to know what other people do in real world projects.

Comment: With C++, you'd write a wrapper (probably using exceptions for error handling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job, though be sure to check for errors after exiting the loop.

```
while((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
...
}
```

Edit: Note that this doesn't account for if the database is busy, but you can correct that either with a conditional `goto` after the loop, or an outside loop that continues while `rc` it's not equal to `SQLITE_DONE`.

Comment: A busy error cannot happen in the middle of a transaction, and should be dealt with with a [busy timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) anyway.

Comment: @CL. Couldn't it happen if SQLite needs to upgrade the lock on a transaction but can't because another process does it first?

Comment: @CL. Yea, the docs for [SQLITE_BUSY](http://sqlite.org/rescode.html#busy) say it can happen in a transaction, unless you use `BEGIN IMMEDIATE`.

Comment: This happens only for transactions that write. Calling `sqlite3_step` in a loop is a sign of a SELECT (which can write only if user-defined functions are involved).